# Hubot with GitHub API to merge in Pull Request not working

Tags: github, hubot

I'm trying to use Hubot to merge a pull request for a specified repository, but I get a response object like this: `{ message: 'Not Found', documentation_url: 'https://developer.github.com/v3' }`.

Here is my code, with the sha removed:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /deploy pr (.*) in (.*)/i, (res) ->
    prNumber = res.match[1]
    repo     = res.match[2]
    owner    = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_OWNER
    base_url = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_API || 'https://api.github.com'
    mergeUrl = "#{base_url}/repos/#{owner}/#{repo}/pulls/#{prNumber}/merge"

    data =
      commit_message: "Merged pull request #{prNumber} into #{repo}",
      sha: "my-sha-here"

    stringData = JSON.stringify data

    res.http(mergeUrl)
    .put(stringData) (err, response, body) ->
      if err
        res.send "Error: #{err}"
      else
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
        res.send parsedBody.message
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think my auth is set up correctly, as I'm able to make a call with the github api to list all open pull requests for a specified repository.

Comment: If you can list pull requests with api call, doesn't mean you can merge them too. Try merging via api call using your auth and make sure if your access token has required permissions to do so.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I wasn't passing my auth in at all. Previous to this, I was using the GitHubot library, which was taking care of passing auth for me. I just have to send it in a header.

Answer (score 2):

I realized I wasn't passing my auth token, as I was previously using a library that did it for me. You can do it in a header like this:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /deploy pr (.*) in (.*)/i, (res) ->
    prNumber = res.match[1]
    repo     = res.match[2]
    owner    = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_OWNER
    base_url = process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_API || 'https://api.github.com'
    mergeUrl = "#{base_url}/repos/#{owner}/#{repo}/pulls/#{prNumber}/merge"

    data =
      commit_message: "Merged pull request #{prNumber} into #{repo}",
      sha: "my-sha-here"

    stringData = JSON.stringify data

    res.http(mergeUrl)
    .header("Authorization", "token #{your-auth-token}")
    .put(stringData) (err, response, body) ->
      if err
        res.send "Error: #{err}"
      else
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
        res.send parsedBody.message
```